# Як буде українською "порожняком"?

Tags: переклад, калька, росіянізм

СУМ пропонує слово [порожняком](http://sum.in.ua/s/porozhnjakom), яке є омофоном російського слова, тому виникає питання, чи це не калька?

Ще я знаходила слово упорожні (наголос на останній склад) і намагаюся зрозуміти, чи це синонім чи єдина правильна форма слова на позначення перевезення без вантажу, без пасажирів.

Comment: так там же у тій самій статті написано "Те саме, що порожнем". До того ж, ясно, що це все від слова "порожній", тож не розумію, чому калька з російської, а не навпаки - в російській з української.

Answer (score 1):

Крім того, що це слово є в СУМі, ми також можемо знайти його і в [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf) (ст. 524) (також там є слово "порожнем" та навіть "порожньом"), які походять від слова "порожній". Висновок - це слово не калька.